# Thue-Morse Sequence in one Line of Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, lambda-calculus

I wrote a definition for the [Thue-Morse squence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) as an infinite list of integers in one line of Haskell:

```
thueMorse = 0:1:f (tail thueMorse) where f = (\(x:xs) -> x:(1 - x):f xs)
```

This is the result of a failed attempt to define the sequence in one line, only in terms of lambda expressions and itself, without let or where expressions (which really ought to be presented on two lines, making the above solution a two liner in spirit). I have been reading a little about lambda calculus, so I thought I would try it as an exercise. I would like to know if something like this is possible in Haskell, and how to do it if it is possible.

```
thueMorse = 0:1:(\f xs -> f f xs) (\f (x:xs) -> x:(1 - x):f f xs) ((\(_:xs) -> xs) thueMorse)
```

The above expression is a little hard to read, so I'll break it down:

```
(\f xs -> f f xs)
```

Takes a function and an argument and applies that function to itself and the argument. Haskell won't evaluate this expression because f has the type `t = t -> a -> a`, which is the crux of my problem.

```
(\f (x:xs) -> x:(1 - x):f f xs)
```

Is the function passed to the previous expression, which will take itself and a list as arguments. This is the part that recursively computes the Thue-Morse sequence. This also has an infinite type `t = t -> [a] -> [a]`.

```
((\(_:xs) -> xs) thueMorse)
```

This is just the equivalent of `(tail thueMorse)`, but written in terms of lambda expressions to meet the conditions of the exercise.

Haskell complains that these expressions have infinite type and refuses to evaluate them, bit I think that if they were evaluated, they would correctly generate the Thue-Morse sequence. Is there any way to twist the interpreter or compiler's arm into evaluating these expressions? Is there a way to adjust the statement so that it can be evaluated but still only use operators from lambda calculus, and in one line?

Comment: If you just want to see whether the algorithm is correct (regardless of its type), you could sprinkle some [`unsafeCoerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html) over the code. Don't do this in production, though.

Comment: You need recursion, so you'll need to have a fix-point operator at some point. You can reuse the standard one (`Data.Function.fix`), define it yourself, or make your definition produce both `thuleMorse` and `f` simultaneously rather than just `thuleMorse`.

Comment: @MadameElyse, thank you for the suggestion! Inserting `unsafeCoerce` makes the interpreter evaluate the expression, and the result is indeed the Thule-Morse sequence! Here it is with `unsafeCoerce` inserted: `thuleMorseUnsafe = 0:1:(\f xs -> unsafeCoerce f f xs) (\f (x:xs) -> x:(1 - x):unsafeCoerce f f xs) ((\(_:xs) -> xs) thuleMorseUnsafe)`. Is there a cleaner looking way to do this?

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes `thuleMorse = 0:1:fix (\f (x:xs) -> x:(1 - x):f xs) (tail thuleMorse)` works perfectly, and I don't have to do anything spooky to get it to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's Thue, not Thule

Comment: @pat, YIKES. I misread it ages ago, and my brain never bothered to correct itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the same algorithm, but without explicit `fix`:

```
thueMorse = 0 : 1 : (tail thueMorse >>= \x -> [x, 1 - x])
```

Comment: This is the most succinct variation so far.

Comment: It's also slightly faster than my fix-based version, to get the 100-millionth element of the sequence took 12.281s using the fix-based version and 11.079s using yours (`ghc -e "..."`). My original version also took more than 12 seconds.